# Running tests in suite and individually

Tags: testing

I have found ways to create method which is called before a test suite. That is what I need. But I also need to run each one of my tests individually, at least in order to develop them. That means, that when a test is run indivially, the before suite method should be run before the single test. My test are located in different classes. I haven't been able to find a logic which runs the before method before suite when running the whole suite, and before test (class) when running one test. Am I pipedreaming here?

Comment: Java, i have been using junit, but curious about testng too

Answer (score 0):

For [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=home) it sounds like you want [FixtureSetup](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.2.10) and [SetUp](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10)

For ms-test I think it is [TestInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [ClassInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: But does this take acount the logic IF suite is run, then the method is operated once, not over and over again before every class?

Comment: I don't know of any instruction that runs once for an entire suite. Only once/testClass and once/test. Maybe you can collect the tests that needs a common initialization into a test class? (My answer is for C#)